# Incorrect overlapping of lines with Unix paste

Tags: files, paste

I have one file called `file1`, which contains the following lines

```
you are searching for a four .
you are searching for a six .
you are searching for a three .
you are searching for an ace .
you are searching for an eight .
you can use empty spaces in the Tab@@ le@@ au to move multiple cards . be careful with K@@ ings in the Reserve : the only way to remove them is by playing them to a Foundation on top of a Queen .
you can use empty spaces in the Tab@@ le@@ au to move multiple cards . be careful with K@@ ings in the Reserve : the only way to remove them is by playing them to a Foundation on top of a Queen .
```

I have a second file called `file2` with these lines

```
four|||Vier
six|||Se@@ chs
for|||nach
searching|||suchen
eight|||Acht
spaces|||Plätze
spaces|||Plätze spaces|||Plätze
```

However, after I executed the command for merging this lines via Unix paste

```
paste file1 file2 > result
```

I get as result this:

```
you are four|||Vieror a four .
you are six|||Se@@ chsa six .
you are for|||nachfor a three .
you are searching|||suchence .
you are eight|||Achtr an eight .
you can use empty spaces in the Tab@@ le@@ au to move multiple cards . be careful with K@@ ings in the Reserve : the only way to remove them is by playing them to a Fouspaces|||Plätzeof a Queen .
you can use empty spaces in the Tab@@ le@@ au to move multiple cards . be careful with K@@ ings in the Reserve : the only way to remove them is by playing them to a Foundation on top of a Queen .     spaces|||Plätze spaces|||Plätze
```

I don't understand what happened. Why are the merged lines from each file overlapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing at least `file1` is a DOS text file. When used on a Unix system, each line in such a file will have an extra carriage-return character at the end. This carriage-return character brings the cursor back to the start of the line when it's printed to the terminal. The tab character that `paste` inserts between the data from the two files move the cursor eight characters to the right. The text from the second file then overwrites the contents of the line from there on, giving rise to the garbled output that you see.

You may want to convert your text files with a tool such as `dos2unix` (this would also correctly convert the files from common Windows text encodings to encoding more commonly used on Unix, etc.)